# Wie vs. Inwiefern/Inwieweit

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Meine Frage ist, ob die zwei Wörter *wie* und *inwiefern* bzw. *inwieweit* leicht unterschiedlich und daher nicht austauschbar sind. Ich hab das Gefühl, man kann *inwiefern* immer durch *wie* ersetzen, aber nicht umgekehrt. Stimmt das oder gibt es spezielle Fälle, wo man *inwiefern* verwenden muss, weil der Satz sonst komisch klingen würde oder eine andere Bedeutung bekommen würde?

PS. Deutsch ist übrigens nicht meine Muttersprache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nein, die drei Wörter haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen
und sind im allgemeinen nicht austauschbar.
Beispiel:

- *"Inwieweit ist die Welt seit 1989 sicherer geworden?"* *("To what extent has the world become a safer place since 1989?
  (It has, but how much?)")*
- *"Inwiefern ist die Welt seit 1989 sicherer geworden?"* *("To what extent has the world become a safer place since 1989?
  Has it at all?" or "What makes you believe that the world has become a safer place since 1989?")*
- *"Wie ist die Welt seit 1989 sicherer geworden?"* *("How has the world become a safer place since 1989?")*

"Inwieweit" und "inwiefern" fragen beide nach dem Ausmaß, aber bei "inwiefern" stellt man auch die Frage, ob die Eigenschaft überhaupt zutrifft
und warum der Gesprächspartner diese Auffassung vertritt.
"Wie" fragt dagegen nach der Art und Weise.

Comment: also mit *inwiefern* man zweifelt, mit *inwieweit* ist das Ausmaß unklar und *wie* ist einfach generell wenns ich's korrekt verstanden hab.

Comment: Ja, richtig. Ich habe den Text ergänzt.

Comment: Ich bin unsicher, ob die Frage zu _Inwiefern_ richtig ist. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/inwiefern)  nennt als Bedeutungen: `auf welche Weise (zustande gekommen), in welcher Hinsicht, wieso [überhaupt]`.  Wäre das dann nicht eher: "How" oder "Why" (immer mit dem Zweifel, ob überhaupt)?

Comment: @Uwe, warum übersetzt du die Fragen überhaupt auf Englisch, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde?

Comment: @Iris Mit "in welcher Hinsicht" bin ich einverstanden, aber
die Übersetzungen "auf welche Weise" und "wieso [überhaupt]" 
finde ich zumindest irreführend.
"Inwiefern" kann nur durch "auf welche Weise" ersetzt werden,
wenn "auf welche Weise" im übertragenen Sinn als Ersatz für
"in welcher Hinsicht" verwendet wird, aber nicht, wenn es im
wörtlichen Sinne nach der Art und Weise fragt.
"Inwiefern" fragt auch nicht nach dem Grund;
wenn ich "inwiefern" durch "wieso" ersetze, dann meine ich nicht "wieso ist das so", sondern
"wieso bist Du der Meinung, daß das so ist".